# Reusing existing CSS in styled-component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

We've a large project that exist of multiple styled components.
But for a next release and design update of that component we'll working together with a new partner that will deliver the styleguide and a CSS file that they are created for our client.

So I'm looking how I can re-use the styles of our partner in a styled component.

Do you think it's a good idea to do something like:

```
const PrimaryButton = styled(".btn-primary)``.
```

Instead of:

```
const PrimaryButton = styled.button``;
```

Actually, I can not find any working example, thus I think it's not possible... So, does someone know how I can do something like this?

Ehm, and for some reason I want to avoid to have something like this...

```
<PrimaryButton className="btn-primary"></PrimaryButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse styled components by extending the styles.

```
const Button = styled.button`
  color: palevioletred;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  border: 2px solid palevioletred;
  border-radius: 3px;
`;
```

```
// A new component based on Button, but with some override styles
const PrimaryButton = styled(Button)`
  color: blue;
  border-color: blue;
`;
```

Comment: Thank you. But some styled-components should re-use an already existing style. Now I did it this way:

`export const SlideDetails = styled.div.attrs((props) => ({
    className: "slide-details",
}))'
  color: #FF0000;
';`